# do i need to install angular if i've installed angula-cli (globally)

Tags: angular, angular-cli

i've installed angular-cli globally on a fresh windows machine

```
npm install -g @angular/cli

ng --version

Angular CLI: 1.6.4
Node: 9.3.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...
```

now, do i need to install angular as well (globally) or the cli automatically installs it as dependecy?

the getting started guid doesn't say anything about it:
https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run

```
ng new MY_PROJECT_NAME; cd MY_PROJECT_NAME; ng serve
```

And you will see.

(Spoilers : the answer is **no**)

Comment: so do i never need to install angular globally if i create my app with the cli?

Comment: No : Angular is a **dependency** of your project, meaning your project will need it to run. Angular CLI, on the other side, is a **script** you run from npm .bin folder, that will create files and launch commandes for yo.

Answer (score 1):

the angular cli is for creating the app and components etc of angular app, so the angular cli create for you the initial boiler plate with all the dependencies with the command 
`ng new newProject` then `cd newProject`
and for start the app `ng serve`
then it create and install all the dependencies in the folder newProject.

hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here , to avoid confusion with `angular` and `angular-cli` ,  think about `windows` and `windows command line (cmd)`, roughly we can compare with it.

If `ng --version` is working, then Angular installation is done. We can go ahead and start creating Angular project. Use `ng serve` to start app. All the dependencies will be done automatically.

Now, when we are creating project, if we need to have installed things inside `node_modules` locally, then use `--save` option from project's root when doing so.